# Laravel Mix: Exclude SASS File from Minifying for Production

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-mix

I am running Laravel 5.4 and using Laravel Mix to compile my assets. I have two SASS files for production. However, one of them needs to be compiled from SASS to CSS without minifying. I don't see how to do that. Here's what I have in my webpack.mix.js file:

```js
mix.js(
    [
        'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    ],
    'public/assets/js'
)
.sass(
    'resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
    'public/assets/css'
)
.sass(
    'resources/assets/sass/pdf.scss',
    'public/assets/css',
)
.version();
```

Now, the pdf.scss file is the one that needs to be "un-minified" for production. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: why you want to do that ? i did not understand. if you dont want to minified css file then just dont write your css in sass file , write direct in a css file and include it in your blade

Comment: This is not what the question was about. I need that file to be un-minified because a PDF library I am using handles minified CSS poorly. I still need that file to be SASS because it uses a lot of styles and shared things from the main file.

Comment: understood. rare situation. froom google search i found this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/unminify . dont know work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a solution to do this.

```
  mix.sass("src/app.scss", "dist/", {
  sassOptions: {
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
  },
```

})

sassOption help you to add some features to sass file.you can see [all option here](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass#javascript-api)".
When you set the value of outputStyle equal to expanded, this will prevent the compression of SCSS files from damaging them. Of course, by doing this, the files will be compressed again.